# LoadableDetachableModel is not refreshed onSubmit and the model is removed from the page

Tags: java, ajax, wicket, wicket-1.5, loadable-component

I am trying to query table and re-render the LoadableDetachableModel with result list.
Table is empty upon page initialization.
After onSubmit method call the table is removed from the page and model is gone.
All I got is below JS error. I can see that the property is not rendered yet but do not know why.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nextSibling')
    at Object.Wicket.replaceOuterHtmlSafari (wicket-ajax.js:214)
    at Object.Wicket.replaceOuterHtml (wicket-ajax.js:222)
    at wicket-ajax.js:931
    at Object.<anonymous> (wicket-ajax.js:91)
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
final WebMarkupContainer listViewContainerForLogTable = new WebMarkupContainer("listViewContainerForLogTable");
        listViewContainerForLogTable.setOutputMarkupId(true);


final LoadableDetachableModel<List<BufferLogs>> bufferLogList = new LoadableDetachableModel<List<BufferLogs>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<BufferLogs> load() {
                return bufferLogsService.getAllLogs();
            };

        };


final PageableListView<BufferLogs> listViewForLogTable = new PageableListView<BufferLogs>("listViewForLogTable", bufferLogList,10) {

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<BufferLogs> item) {

                final BufferLogs mobject = item.getModelObject();

                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
                String date = formatter.format(mobject.getcDate());

                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String time = formatter.format(mobject.getcDate());

                item.add(new Label("id", String.valueOf(mobject.getRowNum()) ));
                item.add(new Label("lineName", mobject.getLineName()));
                item.add(new Label("date", date));
                item.add(new Label("time", time));
                item.add(new Label("short", String.valueOf(mobject.getShortBuffer())));
                item.add(new Label("full", String.valueOf(mobject.getFullBuffer())));
                item.add(new Label("bufferOffset", String.valueOf(mobject.getBufferOffset() == null ? "" : mobject.getBufferOffset() ) ));

            }

        };

        listViewContainerForLogTable.add(listViewForLogTable);


AjaxButton submit = new AjaxButton("submit") {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                target.addComponent(listViewContainerForLogTable);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                target.addComponent(feedbackPanel);

            }

        };

listViewContainerForLogTable.add(navigator);
        add(listViewContainerForLogTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

That JS code is 10 year old from pre- Wicket 1.6. You should upgrade to Wicket 9 (or Wicket 8 at minimum).

Comment: do you think that is a bug on this version?

Comment: From the stacktrace it seems you're running on Safari, a lot of things have changed in the last 10 years.

Comment: i run it on chrome but wicket 1.4.6 thinks it is Safari.

Comment: Then you're right and it's a bug with that version: the Safari detection is flawed. This is why Wicket uses jquery for a long time now.